# Playwright CDPSession

Tags: javascript, performance, playwright

I am playing around with playwrights CDPSession for some performance metrics on my tests, but I have no idea what im reading. The values (such as DomContentLoaded or FirstMeaningfulPaint) seem extremely large to be considered milliseconds. Can someone help me understand the values?

Here is my lastest Perfomancemetrics for simply logging into the application and navigating to a page:

```
[

{ name: 'Timestamp', value: 506849.888122 },

{ name: 'AudioHandlers', value: 0 },

{ name: 'AudioWorkletProcessors', value: 0 },

{ name: 'Documents', value: 41 },

{ name: 'Frames', value: 20 },

{ name: 'JSEventListeners', value: 1024 },

{ name: 'LayoutObjects', value: 2511 },

{ name: 'MediaKeySessions', value: 0 },

{ name: 'MediaKeys', value: 0 },

{ name: 'Nodes', value: 4561 },

{ name: 'Resources', value: 122 },

{ name: 'ContextLifecycleStateObservers', value: 53 },

{ name: 'V8PerContextDatas', value: 3 },

{ name: 'WorkerGlobalScopes', value: 0 },

✓ 1 login.spec.ts:18:5 › [1234] CDP session (7.4s)

{ name: 'RTCPeerConnections', value: 0 },

{ name: 'ResourceFetchers', value: 41 },

{ name: 'AdSubframes', value: 0 },

{ name: 'DetachedScriptStates', value: 4 },

{ name: 'ArrayBufferContents', value: 1 },

{ name: 'LayoutCount', value: 399 },

{ name: 'RecalcStyleCount', value: 753 },

{ name: 'LayoutDuration', value: 0.360929 },

{ name: 'RecalcStyleDuration', value: 0.134134 },

{ name: 'DevToolsCommandDuration', value: 0.165872 },

{ name: 'ScriptDuration', value: 1.009343 },

{ name: 'V8CompileDuration', value: 0.000204 },

{ name: 'TaskDuration', value: 2.238349 },

{ name: 'TaskOtherDuration', value: 0.567867 },

{ name: 'ThreadTime', value: 2.220465 },

{ name: 'ProcessTime', value: 0.390625 },

{ name: 'JSHeapUsedSize', value: 42574364 },

{ name: 'JSHeapTotalSize', value: 55816192 },

{ name: 'FirstMeaningfulPaint', value: 506846.717363 },

{ name: 'DomContentLoaded', value: 506846.199889 },

{ name: 'NavigationStart', value: 506845.029712 }

]
```